# moving an actor model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I can't seem to move actors that get added to the world, they always move a tiny bit and get reset back to their original positions (unlike other models such as spheres). I'm thinking the animation resets the pose, but am new to Gazebo so am a bit unsure as to where to start looking. Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

The sdf that I insert into the world is pretty simple:

```
<sdf version ='1.5'>
    <actor name='actor0'>
        <skin>
            <filename>sitting.dae</filename>
            <scale>1.0</scale>
        </skin>
    </actor>
</sdf>
```

An image for context:

[image: image description]

Thanks for your help!

Jamie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7562/moving-an-actor-model/) by [jdddog](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/652/jdddog/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The actor class does reset the pose. If you just want to have a DAE file that you can move around, you can use:

```
<model name="human">
  <link name="link">
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>file://sitting.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>
```

I winged the above, so there might be some typos. It also is only a visual with no collision.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdddog](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/652/jdddog/) on 2014-11-26**:
Sweet thanks!